# Display String based on int value

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx-8

I have JavaFX Label which I want to use to display different status.

```
int status;

Label finalFieldAgentStatus = new Label();
```

When I have `status = 0` I want to print `finalFieldAgentStatus = "Innactive"`;
When I have `status = 1` I want to print `finalFieldAgentStatus = "Active";`

Is there any smart way automatically to set `finalFieldAgentStatus` string based on  `status` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the type of your status field and use `IntegerProperty`.

By doing that, you can add a binding between this property and the  `label.textProperty()` to autotically change the value when the status changes.

You can read more about bindings here: https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm

**EDIT:**

For example, you can do:

```
IntegerProperty status = new SimpleIntegerProperty( );
Label label = new Label( );
status.addListener( ( observable, oldValue, newValue ) -> {
    label.setText( newValue.intValue( ) == 1 ? "Active" : "Inactive" );
} );
```

or you can do:

```
IntegerProperty status = new SimpleIntegerProperty( );
Label label = new Label( );
label.textProperty( ).bind( Bindings.createStringBinding(
        ( ) -> status.intValue( ) == 1 ? "Active" : "Inactive", status ) );
```

Comment: @PeterPenzov I have just edited my answer to add this link with many example of bindings : https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/binding/jfxpub-binding.htm

Comment: Thanks, which one is better if I want to use less memory and CPU?

Comment: I think differences between both solution are insignificant... Take the one you think the clearest. But if you have specific and strict constraints you can benchmark it with JMH or other library to make your choice